# Eloquent eager loading with hasMany relation doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My code currently doesn't work, but my relations are correct.

**Project model**

```
public function timeEntries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\TimeEntries');
}

$array_of_project = Project::with('timeEntries')
    ->whereBetween('spent_on', [($request->debut)), ($request->fin))])
    ->get();
```

It doesn't find 'spent_on.'

Comment: return $this->hasMany('App\Model\TimeEntries', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Comment: Is `spent_on` part of Project or TimeEntries? If it's TimeEntries, then you need to add a closure/subquery into the `with`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to constrain the relation's records. I suggest looking at the documentation for constraining eager loading. Here is a code sample of what I think you are trying to accomplish:

```
$projects = App\Model\Project::with(['timeEntries' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->whereBetween('spent_on', $request->debut, $request->fin);
}])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 0):

Like @aynber wrote, if your `spent_on` attribute is part of the related model, it should be included in the query with a closure.

```php
$array_of_project = Project::with(['timeEntries' => function ($time_entry) use ($request) {
    $time_entry->whereBetween('spent_on', [$request->input('debut'), $request->input('fin')]);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `spent_on` is a column in the `time_entries` table then your `whereBetween` is not correct since it will look inside the `projects` table. But you can add it to `with` instead:

```php
$array_of_project = Project::with(['timeEntries' => function($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->whereBetween('spent_on', [$request->input('debut'), $request->input('fin')]);
})->get();
```